# Pyinstaller generates the exe ok, but it does not work

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4, pyinstaller

I'm having problems running the exe generated by pyinstaller.
The only warning I get is this:

```
11171 WARNING: Hidden import "setuptools.msvc" not found!
```

the rest is okay. When i run the program, two windows (cmd) open and they close automatically.

I'm using:

Python 3.4.4

Pyinstaller 3.4

Windows 10 64b

The Pyinstaller command is

```
pyinstaller.exe asd/forcelogoff.py
```

And the code is it (Works ok):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import paramiko
import os
import cffi
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, font
# Gestor de geometría (pack)
class Aplicacion():
    def __init__(self):
        self.raiz = Tk()
        self.raiz.title("Force Logoff Agent Asterisk")
        fuente = font.Font(weight='bold')
        self.etiq1 = ttk.Label(self.raiz, text="Agente:",
                           font=fuente)
        self.agente = StringVar()
        self.ctext1 = ttk.Entry(self.raiz,
                            textvariable=self.agente,
                            )
        self.separ1 = ttk.Separator(self.raiz, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.boton1 = ttk.Button(self.raiz, text="Aceptar",
                             command=self.aceptar)
        self.boton2 = ttk.Button(self.raiz, text="Cancelar",
                             command=sys.exit(0))
        self.etiq1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True,
                    padx=5, pady=5)
        self.ctext1.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, expand=True,
                     padx=5, pady=5)
        self.separ1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True,
                     padx=5, pady=5)
        self.boton1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True,
                     padx=5, pady=5)
        self.boton2.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=True,
                     padx=5, pady=5)
        self.ctext1.focus_set()
        self.raiz.mainloop()

    def aceptar(self):
        PASSWD = "PASS"
        HOST = "IP"
        AGENT = "Agent/" + str(self.agente.get())
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_host_keys(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),     'known_hosts'))
        client.connect("%s" % (HOST), port=22, username="root",     password="%s" % (PASSWD), auth_timeout=10)
        stdin, stdout, stderr= client.exec_command("/pbx/obelix    /pbx/sbin/asterisk -rx 'agent logoff %s'" % (AGENT))
        print ("Conexión SSH exitosa.")
        print ("Ejecutando comando...")
        print (stdout.decode("utf-8"))
        print ("Cerrando conexión...")      
        stdout = stdout.read()
        client.close()
        print ("Conexión Cerrada")
        print (" ")

def main():
    mi_app = Aplicacion()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried *freeze* instead of pyinstaller?

Comment: how i use it ? I dont locate freeze.py in my python path.

Comment: freeze is a compiler like pyinstaller. It make exe files.

Comment: it's own of python ? or i need install it ?

Comment: It needs to be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get your code to run decompiled. You see on line 25 it says `command=sys.exit(0))`, this means that as soon as the app is launched, it closes immediately. I changed it to `command=lambda: sys.exit(0))`, using a lambda function so that `sys.exit()` is inly called when the button is pressed. I'm not entirely sure how you got this to work on your system. Then I compiled it using

```
pyinstaller forcelogoff.py --onefile
```

And it worked for me, although I am on Linux.